# Baked lightmap: Parts of scene appear too dark

Tags: unity, lighting, lightmap

I'm having trouble setting up global illumination in my Unity 2021.1.1 URP project

Parts of my scene are appearing completely dark, I'm only using directional light and area light on the windows, here's the baked lightmap view: [image]

In the corner as you can see it's completely dark

[image]

Here's the Shaded view: [image]

The corner again

[image]

Generally the whole scene is pretty dark, it'd like to brighten it up a bit, but the corner is just horrendous.

Those are my lighting settings

[image]

Also the Environment settings as per request:

[image]

Comment: Since your scene is dark and you want to light up the overall ambient, how about editing the [tonemapping](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.0/manual/post-processing-tonemapping.html) properties? So that the absolute lightning in your scene stays the same, but you can change the way colours are drawn on the screen, both on a global and per-volume basis.

Comment: @liggiorgio tonemapping mode is set to Neutral atm

Comment: Can you also include your environment lighting settings? (Window > Rendering > Lighting, Environment tab)

Comment: @liggiorgio updated